# How to develop Flutter app and related package at same time in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a Flutter app and a package folder loaded in VS code at the same time within a workspace.  What entry do I need to make to my app's pubspec.yaml file to ensure that changes I've made to the package are compiled and included whenever I hot reload or restart the app?  What would be an alternate strategy if this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `pubspec.yaml` refers to your package with a `path` then I would expect this to happen automatically. If not, I would consider it a bug. Please file an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code and include a log file generated by running the [**Dart: Capture Logs** command](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#capture-logs-command) and as much info about your project layout as possible (a clonable repo to repro would be perfect).

Comment: ah, was not aware that we could reference other projects via file paths.  I'll give this a shot when I get home later today, thanks!

Comment: There's some info on this at https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages. If you're not doing that today, presumably the package being loaded by your app is from Pub, so Dart doesn't really know that the other project you have open is the same thing. By loading it locally, the paths should match up so the debugger knows they're the same.

If it doesn't seem to work, feel free to file a bug against the Dart-Code repo and we can get to the bottom of it.